# string length in x64 assembly (fasm)

Tags: strings, assembly, x86

Please critique this very, very basic routine which returns the length of a given char buffer or "string."

```
strlen: ; NOTE: RDI IS THE DEFAULT SRC FOR SCASB
    push rdi
    push rcx
    xor rcx, rcx
    mov rcx, -1 

    xor al, al
    cld

    repne scasb 
    neg rcx    
    sub rcx, 1    
    mov rax, rcx 
    pop rcx
    pop rdi
    ret
```

Comment: I would be helpful to indicate whether you're coding to the [Sys V ABI](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf) or the [Microsoft ABI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) for AMD64.

Comment: don't use `xor al, al`. In general avoid partial register update like that

Comment: You may want to insert endbr64 as the first instruction for CET (Control-Flow Enforcement Technology).

Answer (score 12):

Saving `rcx` is usually not necessary, it is not callee-save in common calling conventions. On Linux (and similar) `rdi` also does not need to be saved, I guess you're using that since the Win64 calling convention does not pass an argument in `rdi`. You can save them anyway if you want, which can be useful if you're using custom calling conventions. Saving an even number of registers makes the stack not-16-aligned though, you will probably get away with that now, but for example if you call some function that uses XMM registers it may save them at locations that it assumes are aligned (and there are some other cases where it causes trouble).

```
xor rcx, rcx
mov rcx, -1
```

The `xor` is not useful, `rcx` does not need to be zeroed before overwriting it for correctness reasons, and simply `mov`-ing into a 64 (or 32) bit register already has no dependency on the previous value. By the way, when you *do* want to zero a 64bit register, you can use a 32bit `xor` since writing to the low 32 bits of a register zeroes out the top half of the 64 bit register. There is not really an immediate performance difference, but using the 32bit version often lets you save the REX prefix, unless of course one of the "numbered registers" is an operand.

Because `-x - 1= ~x + 1 - 1 = ~x` (using the definition of two's complement, `-x = ~x + 1`) and you don't use the flags set by the `sub`,

```
neg rcx    
sub rcx, 1    
mov rax, rcx
```

is equivalent to:

```
not rcx
mov rax, rcx
```

So all combined, this function could be simplified slightly to (assuming saving `rdi` and `rcx` is useful):

```
strlen:
    push rdi
    push rcx
    mov rcx, -1
    xor eax, eax
    repne scasb 
    not rcx
    mov rax, rcx 
    pop rcx
    pop rdi
    ret
```

Comment: How do you feel about `xor ecx, ecx ; dec rcx` (5 bytes) instead of `mov rcx, -1` (7 bytes)?  Or even `lea rcx, -1[rax]` (4 bytes)?  But more importantly: comments.  When it comes to asm, I'm a big fan of *lots* of comments.  In particular, if registers are being saved for custom calling reasons (or whatever), you'd certainly want some comments saying so.

Comment: [`xor r32, r32` should be used even for the high numbered registers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666617/995714#comment69763766_33668295), since `xor r64, r64` is not recognized in KNL. @DavidWohlferd see [Set all bits in CPU register to 1 efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45105164/995714)

Comment: @phuclv That link seems to like my `lea rcx, -1[rax]` solution, since we already have a zeroed register we can use (rax).

Comment: Note that if you want this `strlen(rdi)` to return the same value as `size_t strlen(const char *s);` from `<string.h>`, you still need to subtract 1 from `rcx` because "`strlen()` calculates the length of the string pointed to by s, excluding the terminating null byte".